# Manipulating input before using it with CodeIgniter's Form Validation Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Since you can't do this: `$this->form_validation->set_rules($VARIABLE, 'Some text', 'required');`, is it possible to do something similar to:

```
$variable = $this->input->post('some_input');
$variable = some_function_which_manipulates_the_input($variable);

$this->form_validation->set_rules($i_want_the_variable_here, '', '');
```

to manipulate the input before validation check? Adding a custom callback seems a little clumsy to me since one method could do several things (not necessarily targeted at X validation field).

Answer (score 2):

> Since you can't do this: $this->form_validation->set_rules($VARIABLE, 'Some text', 'required');

You certainly *can* do that, as long as `$VARIABLE` contains the `name` attribute of the field you want to validate.

It looks like you're passing the actual `$_POST` value as the first parameter of `set_rules()` - it should in fact be the field name. See the section on setting rules:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules

> $this->form_validation->set_rules();
>
> The above function takes three
>   parameters as input:
>
> - The field name - the exact name you've given the form field.
> - A "human" name for this field, which will be inserted into the error
>     message.Names.
> - The validation rules for this form field.

If you want to alter the actual value of the input before or after validation, just add one or more "prepping" rules.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#preppingdata

> Any native PHP function that accepts one parameter can be used as a rule, like htmlspecialchars, trim, MD5, etc.
>
> Note: You will generally want to use the prepping functions after the validation rules so if there is an error, the original data will be shown in the form.

You may use the rules before as well, if you want to `trim()` something *before* validating for instance. Callbacks will work as well, they serve the same purpose as any function of the form validation library, or any vanilla php functions - validate the data by returning TRUE/FALSE, or alter the data - just note that by default, the callback must belong to the controller the validation is run in. You may use your own helper functions as well, anything that is available to the current script at the point when the data is validated.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify `$_POST` directly, before form validation.

For example

```
// Populate slug automatically
if (!$this->input->post('slug'))
{
    $_POST['slug'] = url_title($this->input->post('title'), '-', true);
}

$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('slug', 'Slug', 'trim|required|is_unique[categories.slug]');

if ($this->form_validation->run())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put the input values into an array prior to validation rules.  I dont know what manipulation you want to do but you can do things like this

```
 $dat = array(
           'fname' => filter_var($this->input->post('fname'), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
           'lname' => filter_var($this->input->post('lname'), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
           'email' => filter_var($this->input->post('email'), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),
           'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
           'relate' => filter_var($this->input->post('relate'), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
            );
$this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required|trim|min_length[3]');
```

then on to

```
 $this->db->update('contacts', $dat);
```

You can use most any thing in the array to manipulate it prior to setting rules

Comment: This doesn't manipulate the input before validation, it just creates a new array of data which *could* be useful *after* validation, but redundant because ideally - you've already filtered and validated the data before processing with the form validation library. In other words, the input being validated will **not** be the `$dat` array.

Comment: He asked how to manipulate the data prior to validation, he could use almost any function such as ucwords, strip tags etc. I just gave an example of manipulation with filter var.  I always create this array before the validation even if I dont do any manipulating of the data.  The data still gets validated by the form validation no matter what. But I accept your point

Comment: This would only work if you actually modified the `$_POST` array directly before validating it. In addition, any prepping rules used would be ignored if you chose to do that in this way. The data being validated is the `$_POST` data, not the values of the array you created. The data you're passing to the model is not the validated data. Am I making sense or missing something?

Comment: No you are not missing anything, I see what you are saying and say you are right